# Should I enable Intel virtualization technology?

Tags: bios, virtualization

I am using Android studio for Android programming it is demanding Intel virtualization technology to get enable to use Android emulator should I enable it? Is it safe to enable it? I have Intel i3 processor.

Comment: Of course its safe and since its required, if you want to do android programming, you really don't have a choice.  You should verify your hardware actually supports it before you proceed further down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  Visualization just allows your computer to respond to a specific process in a certain way.

By all means, it's fine.